# AutoComplete with hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

i'm a newbie with AJAX, and i need help for my autocomplete function. I need to put the ID of the user's choice in an hidden input. I tried many things, but that was not concluding .. At the moment, nothing out of my function. I show you my code :

My JS code :

```
$( "#recherche" ).autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        serviceUrl: 'rechercheadherant.php',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            keyword: request.term
        },
        success: function(data){
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.label,
                    value: item.value    
                }
            }));
         }
    })
}
select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#id").val(ui.item.value);
}
```

});

My php code (rechercheadherant.php):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['query'])) {

    // Mot tapé par l'utilisateur
    $q = htmlentities($_GET['query']);
    $searchArray = array();
    // Connexion à la base de données
    require_once('lib/pdoconnect.php');

    // Requête SQL
    $requete = "SELECT `Ad_Id`, `Ad_Nom`, `Ad_Prenom`, `Ad_DateDeNaissance` FROM `adherant` WHERE `Ad_Nom` LIKE '". $q ."%' LIMIT 0, 10";

    // Exécution de la requête SQL
    $resultat = $connection->query($requete) or die(print_r($connection->errorInfo()));

    // On parcourt les résultats de la requête SQL
    while($search = $resultat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // On ajoute les données dans un tableau
        $DateNaissance = $search["Ad_DateDeNaissance"];
        $FormatDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($DateNaissance));

        $NomPrenom=$search['Ad_Nom']." ".$search['Ad_Prenom']." ".$FormatDate;

        $link = '';
        $link .= $search['Ad_Id'].', '.$search['Ad_Nom'].' '.$search['Ad_Prenom'].', '.$search['Ad_DateDeNaissance'];

        array_push($searchArray, array('label'=> $link, 'value' => $link, 'id'=>$search['Ad_Id']));
}

echo json_encode($searchArray);
```

?>

and my input :

```
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Saisir le nom de l'adhérant recherché" type="text" id="recherche">
          <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">
```

Thanks you in advance :)

Comment: Can you post a example of data returned by your PHP code, please ?

Comment: I'm sorry but, i dont know how see the Json var :x

Comment: Use `console.log(data);` in your `success` fucntion before `reponse...` and look what's in the console of your browser.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data
m.parseJSON()
 jquery.min.js:4
b/g.transformResult()
 jquery.autocomplete.min.js:8
b.prototype.getSuggestions/g.currentRequest<()
 jquery.autocomplete.min.js:8
m.Callbacks/j()
 jquery.min.js:2
m.Callbacks/k.fireWith()
 jquery.min.js:2
x()
 jquery.min.js:4
.send/b()

Comment: So, your Json is the faulty part.

Comment: the problem is in the php file so ?

Comment: It seems.. Try to access directly the url called by Ajax, so you'll be able to see what is generated by PHP.

Comment: i force $q var to "g" and that is generated :
[{"label":"1, Grignon Fran\u00e7ois, 1994-11-08","value":"1, Grignon Fran\u00e7ois, 1994-11-08","id":"1"},{"label":"3, Guillemont Victoria, 1997-06-18","value":"3, Guillemont Victoria, 1997-06-18","id":"3"}]
Its right for this

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your JS code, especially a missing comma (,) before `select`event:

```
$("#recherche").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            serviceUrl: 'rechercheadherant.php',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
            keyword: request.term
            },
            success: function(data){
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#id").val(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

Here is a complete working example.
HTML file:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#recherche").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'data.json',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    keyword: request.term
                },
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert(data.statusText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#id").val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Saisir le nom de l'adhérant recherché" type="text" id="recherche">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">
```

data.json file based on the JSON data you gave:

```
[{"label":"1, Grignon Fran\u00e7ois, 1994-11-08","value":"1, Grignon Fran\u00e7ois, 1994-11-08","id":"1"},{"label":"3, Guillemont Victoria, 1997-06-18","value":"3, Guillemont Victoria, 1997-06-18","id":"3"}]
```

Comment: i added this comma

Comment: and what happens ?

Comment: The same, that was not the main problem.

Comment: Updated answer. I refer to this exmaple in the documentation, you don't need to reformat your data: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: There's no need to use `map` function, each item of your json array contains a property named `label`and another called `value` so that's enough for your autocomplete to work.

Comment: Thanks for ur explain, i do it but my console said to me this again : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: And it is located where in the JSON ?

Comment: with your new update i dont have this error, but i need change " url: 'data.json'," by my php file ?

Comment: Yes, I used "data.json" to make tests locally.

Comment: Okey its done, but I see u use Error function, she return me an alert box with "[object Object]".

Comment: So you have an error in the ajax request. I update the answer to have the error message displayed in the alert box.

Comment: Nop, in the alert box its write "OK". Its very strange XD

Comment: So, you'll need to use tools like Fiddler to debug what's happening between your php file and your browser.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#recherche').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
    $('#id').val(ui.item.value);
});
```